# Can Rek'Sai get knocked up when burrowed?

Tags: league-of-legends

So i was wondering since Rek'sai is still targetable when burrowed if she is still vulnerable for stuns/snares/binds/knock-ups/etc. Now snares, binds and stuns i could understand but since Rek'sai her ability is called 'Burrow' and she litteraly burrows into the ground (ok maybe just for a bit and not for her entire body) it seems unlikely that one slam of alistar or the three talon strike of xin would knock her straight out of the ground. Is my assumption correct? Can Rek'sai be snared/stuned/bound/knocked-up even when burrowed?

Comment: She's vulnerable for any cc but you got me with the knock-up part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They specifically said in the champion intro (or maybe the Q&A) that she is not invulnerable to knockup. She will knock-up and then re-burrow.

[image]

Comment: such a realisitc game :D we can still just see the upper half... did cho'gath rip her in half?

Comment: Her? Teach me too not to check the champ infos.

Comment: Nice screenshot lol

Comment: Can't take the credit for it, found it through google :)